# Tkinter conditional formatting: change color if previous value is not equal?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I would like to have conditional formatting in tkinter.
The program should color by yellow only values if previous column value is different,
like the photo.

[image]

```
import tkinter
import csv

root = tkinter.Tk()

# open file
with open("dati/esempio.csv", newline = "") as file:
   reader = csv.reader(file)

   # r and c tell us where to grid the labels
   r = 0
   for col in reader:
      c = 0
      for row in col:
         # i've added some styling
         label = tkinter.Label(root, width = 10, height = 2, \
                               text = row, relief = tkinter.RIDGE, background='lightblue')
         label.grid(row = r, column = c)
         c += 1
      r += 1

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Put all of the labels in a 2D array and then just loop through each column. Also you can simplify your code if you used the built in `enumerate` function instead of adding 1 to `c`/`r` each time in the for loop

Comment: You've given us a specification, but you haven't asked a question. Stackoverflow isn't intended to be a free coding service. What part of the problem do you need help with?

Answer (score 0):

You can store the previous value and use an if-statement to check and set the color. Then you set the color as background for your label.

```
   r = 0
   for col in reader:
      c = 0
      prev_value = col[0]
      for row in col:
          if row != prev_value:
              col = 'yellow'
              prev_value = row
          else:
              col = 'lightblue'

          tkinter.Label(root, width = 10, height = 2,
                        text = row, relief = tkinter.RIDGE,
                        background=col).grid(row = r, column = c)

         [..your code..]
```

Comment: Excuse me, I tried but is opposite than I requested. With your method change color between columns and previous, while i'm searching the change color between data row and previous data row